# Create npm package using webpack

Tags: node.js, npm, package, webpack

I'm creating an npm package and using webpack for loader like babel, eslint etc.. However I'm under assumption that final compiled version of the package should only contain that one module, without [webpackBootstrap](https://gist.github.com/MartinTale/8224aca378667a6c1fdc#file-webpackbootstrap-js).

My current [package, webpack config and source](https://gist.github.com/MartinTale/4ca0043f3b689fbd898b). I stripped it down to just make it "work".

Steps I took to check if it's working:

```
npm install
npm run build
npm install -g .
node
var test = require('test-package');
```

Resulting in this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'test-package'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at repl:1:12
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:248:27)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:412:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
```

I'm new to webpack and npm so let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set [output.libraryTarget](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget) to `umd`. That will give you something that's easy to consume from various module systems (global, AMD, CommonJS).

[output.library](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-library) is another useful field to set. That should match the name of your library global you want.

---

There was another problem beyond this. To make the import work `npm link` needed be used. This feature is highly useful during development. You can revert a link through `npm unlink`.

Comment: While I have added these changes - the package still doesn't work. I have updated the question with a link to stripped down config/source and steps I'm taking to check if package is working/installable/usable.

Comment: Based on error I would say it could be something npm related. Why not to use `npm link`? Btw I have sorted out these kind of issues at my [boilerplate](https://github.com/survivejs/react-component-boilerplate). It does a lot for you if you have time to study its approaches.

Comment: Use of npm link was the key.. I'm very new to javascript/nodejs but I learn quickly.. If you update your answer with the npm link part (in addition to config info you already provided) then I can accept your answer. I had a look at your boilerplate. There is a lot there but it looks good - going to go through it step by step after I finish my first package.

Comment: Thanks. Added. I have [a chapter](http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/authoring_libraries/) where I go through the techniques. That might be easier to digest than the boilerplate.