# Webpack2, how to exclude react and react dom from build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, jsx, react-dom

My goal is to create a module for a react components library made in ES6 using webpack.

I am using:

- webpack: "2.1.0-beta.25"
- react: "15.4.1"

I need to assign `react` and `react-dom` as peerDependencies so it doesn't get downloaded by the developer.

This is the relevant part of my `package.json`:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "15.4.1"
},
"dependencies": {
  "chalk": "1.1.3",
  "compression": "1.6.2",
  "cross-env": "3.1.3",
  "immutable": "3.8.1",
  "invariant": "2.2.1",
  "lodash": "4.16.4",
  "minimist": "1.2.0",
  "sanitize.css": "4.1.0",
  "warning": "3.0.0",
  "react-onclickoutside": "5.8.3",
  "styled-components": "1.1.2",
  "classnames": "2.2.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "react": "15.4.1",
  "react-dom": "15.4.1",
```

According to https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals and https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html,

I have tried the following configuration :

1.

```
externals: {
  react: {
    root: 'React',
    commonjs2: 'react',
    commonjs: 'react',
    amd: 'react'
  },
  'react-dom': {
    root: 'ReactDOM',
    commonjs2: 'react-dom',
    commonjs: 'react-dom',
    amd: 'react-dom'
  }
},
```

2.
    externals: {
      react: 'react',
      'react-dom' : 'react-dom',
    }

3.

```
 externals: {
  react: 'React',
  'react-dom' : 'ReactDOM',
 }
```

4.

```
externals: {
  react: 'umd react',
  'react-dom' : 'umd react-dom'
}
```

5.

```
    externals: {
        // Use external version of React
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },
```

I always have this error :

```
 Dynamic page loading failed Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded (details: https://bf.me/react-refs-must-have-owner).(…)
```

So I wonder, the documentation isn't very clear on that.

In december 2017, january 2018 at maximum, how can I exclude `React` and `ReactDOM` from being bundled ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is react complaining of existing multiple time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351128/why-is-react-complaining-of-existing-multiple-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be put them into separate file such as `reactjs` via

```
  entry: {
      app:'./src/app.jsx',
      reactjs:[
          'react','react-dom'               ,
      ]
  }

  output: {
    path       : path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename   : 'bundle.[name].js',
    publicPath : '/public/'
  },

 plugins : [
     new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'reactjs',
     })
 ]
```

So now `webpack` will build two files `bundle.app.js` and `bundle.reactjs.js`.
Include them in your `index.html` first react then app.

Comment: I am currently trying your solution but I am surprise if there is not a cleaner way, this will generate useless file that I will have to exclude in the .npmignore and .gitignore. Not sure if it work I'll test and tell you

Comment: In any case you should not include generated build files to git

Comment: Well, I have the following error now : webpackJsonpbootstrap_styled is not defined. "So now webpack will build two files bundle.app.js and bundle.reactjs.js. Include them in your index.html first react then app." Also, this is note an application, this a npm package this is why I don't wan't React at all.

Comment: You should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131367/create-npm-package-using-webpack

Comment: I already have set my module to umd, the umd works fine, my module work perfect, the only issue is that it complain of a second instance of react which is obviously the one bundled with the module. As soon as I've tried with your technique, the size reduce from 900ko to (650kb +250kb (bundle.react.js)). On the other hand, I didn't imported the react bundle. Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

here my webpack configuration, it just the basics since I'm working on a smaller project

```
const {resolve} = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './demo/react/main.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'demo/react/dist')
  }
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        ]

      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    // Use external version of React
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

Did not see this in your tried example. As mentioned by OP, the following JSON config did not work for them.

---

From [GitHub issue #1275](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1275#issuecomment-176255624), try this:

```
{
    externals: {
        // Use external version of React
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, try reading through that whole Issue page. There are a couple of suggestion that may end up working for you.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see that in your list of tried examples. My bad. Good luck!

Comment: yeah, that worked for me :), I just need those been delivered via CDN